# Override proxy's incorrect Content-Type

Tags: nginx

I have an origin with all kind of files (css/js/jpg/png...) but for protection reasons it returns incorrect Conent-Type for all files.

I want to proxy that origin and serve those files.

Is there any way to have Nginx replace the Content-Type header with a correct one when using proxy_pass?

Comment: Why can't you fix the broken origin server?

Comment: I don't control the origin. I want to use its content and the owner is cool with it but they cant fix the MIMEs only for my IP.

Answer (score 2):

nginx's Headers More module should do the trick. http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule tells more about the module.

You might need to compile your own version of nginx, since this is a third party module.